# do I host both, back-end and front-end?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, devops, netlify, web-frontend

I'm having a MERN stack app, so at first I thought that I'll host my whole app in my vps, and then when a user tries to access the website,my vps will execute the back-end (nodejs)and then it will send the fornt-end (react.js) to the client browser, and then the browser will render it.
but just now I watched a tutorial ([ben Awad's](https://youtu.be/Kx_1NYYJS7Q?t=827)), and he said that you can host the backend in vps, and host the front-end (react.js) in another server like netlify.
so which one is correct? and if the second, tell me more

Comment: Why would you use two separate hosting providers?  Just because you can doesn't mean you should.  FYI, that video pretty much explains things - if you don't understand something specific in that video, I'd suggest you ask a more specific question about something they said in the video.  If you're only hosting static resources, you can put them wherever is most efficient and cost effective (though on your VPS probably works just fine too).  Otherwise with any server-side rendering, host on your VPS.

Comment: FYI, if you're new to this, I'd keep things as simple as possible (one hosting provider) and only make things more complicated when it is obvious why you should do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear, a React application doesn't serve itself. It's all in-browser. You would need to have some sort of server-side piece to serve it up. That being said, there are all sorts of different places you could put it. A CDN if you need one, S3 if you use aws, or you could simply serve it up as static assets from your backend application. As far as what's right, it's dependent. If you need server side rendering, for example, you'll have to serve it up yourself. If not, you can serve it however makes the most sense for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use 2 separate hosting providers , you can but why complicate things if you don't need it .You can host both frontend and backend on netlify no issues

Comment: what? Backend on netlify? I thought it only serves websites

Comment: You can, but the only problem is you backend code will be exposed